# How to access a subfolder in Outlook inbox in Python

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

I have created a rule in Outlook to move all incoming messages from a particular sender to a subfolder in my Inbox.Like -

```
Inbox
- Subfolder
```

I wrote a piece of code

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) #6 = Inbox (without mails from the subfolder)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body 
print body_content #Sometimes has parsing error due to different encoding format
```

How can I

1) Read the mails in this particular folder inside Inbox

2) Take care of error like UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode - character maps to

`print (u'\2109')` issues this error too.

Comment: have you tried `body_content.encode('cp1252')` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - print (u'\2109').encode('cp1252') - same error

Comment: try `utf-8` then.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - utf-8 worked. Thanks.. I tried ASCII and had given up :P

Answer (score 4):

outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) is "Inbox" position by default. You need to traverse the list of folders in it, so try this

```
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("Your_Folder_Name")
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Hey there! Do you know if it's possible to access a subfolder of a subfolder? 
In the list of folders in the mailbox I have a folder and under that  I have another folder that I can't access

Comment: @Jewlanu were you able to access sub-sub folder?

Answer (score 2):

`u'\2109'` looks a lot like UTF-8 encoding.

So `print(body_content.encode("utf-8"))` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
> mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
>
> inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["SubFolder"]
> mails = inbox.Items
> ```

The above method will also work.