# How to read email messages from outlook inbox sub folder

Tags: python, email, outlook

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
body_content = message.body
print body_content
```

I have an outlook email account.
The inbox has a sub folder : calls 
I want to read email messages from this sub folder in python
i am using win32com.client here is what i am doing. I can access inbox but not sub folder in that

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please see [Ask] and [help] to properly format your question to a specific one with an [MCVE].

Comment: I recommend using POP/IMAP for this. If you don't know what that is, read up on the subject (before you go pywin32)

Comment: i am using win32com.client here is what i am doing. I can access inbox but not sub folder in that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlook using python win32com to iterate subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849742/outlook-using-python-win32com-to-iterate-subfolders)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to traverse the list of folders in Inbox, like this:

```
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("Your_Folder_Name")
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[How to access a subfolder in Outlook inbox in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41563286/how-to-access-a-subfolder-in-outlook-inbox-in-python?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

you may use the following :

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders['sub_folder_name']